# Differential equation $y' + yx - 2 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to see different methods to solve the differential equation $$y' + yx - 2 = 0.$$ Thank you in advance.

**Update** Since the question has been put on hold as if it misses context I think it best to edit it so as to improve its body. Since I am unfamiliar with the theory of differential equations, I worked rather intuitively when I was first given this problem. It occurred to me that $y$ is asymptotic to $\overline {y}$ where $\overline {y} x - 2 = 0$. Hence, $y \sim 2/x$ for large $x$. That is why I thought of expressing $y$ as an infinite series. Let $$y = \frac {2} {x} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f_n (x),$$ where $f_n$ are real functions. Working recursively, I arrived at the opinion that $$f_n (x) = \frac {2} {x^{2 n + 1}} \prod_{k = 1}^{n} (2k - 1).$$ This led me to $$y = \frac {2} {x} + 2 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {(2n - 1)!!} {x^{2n + 1}}.$$ This happened to satisfy the equation.

Comment: The equation can be put in the form $y' + p(x) y = q(x)$, so one can solve this by multiplying by an appropriate integrating factor. (In this case, the integrating factor is especially easy...)

Comment: the solution containes the error function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by some function $\mu(x)$:

$$\mu(x)y'+\mu(x)xy=2\mu(x)$$

so that $$\mu'(x)=\mu(x)x\implies \frac{\mu'}{\mu}=x\implies \ln(\mu)=\frac12x^2$$

$$\mu(x)=\exp(x^2/2)$$

Now, use the identity $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$:

$$\mu(x)y'+\mu'(x)y=2\mu(x)$$
$$(\mu(x)y)'=2\mu(x)$$
$$\mu(x)y=\int 2\mu(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks! The last integral is the error function with complex variable. No elementary solution, huh?

Comment: @NimaBavari yes, you can solve it using substitution $t=ix/\sqrt2$ and $\rm{erf}$ function, or $t=x/\sqrt2$ and $\rm{erfi}$ function. No elementary solution exists

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use integrating factor. That is multiply the equation by $e^{\int x dx}$